# concatenate two strings that are in different lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I need to concatenate two strings that are in different lists and check if the output string is in a dictionary. The code I've tried is:

```
x=['casa','lo','pre','computer']
y=['music','sun','ve','sident','house']
dic=['sunday','love','president','house','computer']
text=[]
errors=[]
iter_y=iter(y)
iter_x=iter(x)

for i in iter_x:
    if i in dic:
        text.append(i)
    else:
        try:
            concatenated= i + next(iter_y)
            if concatenated in dic:
                text.append(concatenated)
      except StopIteration:
          continue
        else:
            errors.append(i)
   print (text)
```

This code is returning only the word that is common to x and y ('Computer'). My desired output is x=[love, president, computer] That is, with the words love and president concatenated in the output.

Comment: `except StopIteration:
          continue
        else:
            errors.append(i)` Fishhhyyyyy part

Comment: *This code is returning only the word that is common to x and y ('Computer').* `y` doesn't even have `Computer`

Comment: Shouldn't output be `computer', 'house', 'love', 'president'`? including `house`?

Comment: Again how do you tell the system to match `lo` from `x` wih `ve` from `y`?

Comment: @DirtyBit, that's the whole point. If the match is available in `dic`, it should be in output.

Comment: @Austin still trying to grasp it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your approach, you need to reset the iterator over `y` each time you try a new value in `x`.

It might be clearer like this:

```
for i in x:
  if i in dic:
    text.append(i)
  else:
    for j in y:
      concatenated = i + j
      if concatenated in dic:
        text.append(concatenated)
```

The `for j in y` tries all the things in `y`, otherwise it moves on each time, and never looks back.

Comment: Shouldn't the output be `['love', 'president', 'computer', 'house']` ?

Comment: The desired output mentioned in the question doesn't say `house`; but that might be an oversight. Let's see.

Comment: @DirtyBit The OP said: _"My desired output is **x=[love, president, computer]**"_.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC then you can use `itertools.product` to get product of two different lists and then perform set intersection to find the common words

```
from itertools import product
x=['casa','lo','pre','computer']
y=['music','sun','ve','sident','house']
dic=['sunday','love','president','house','computer']
set(list(map(''.join, list(product(x, y)))) + x + y) & set(dic)
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'computer', 'house', 'love', 'president'}
```

If the expected output should not include `house` from second list then do not append list `y` in the final concatenated list

```
set(list(map(''.join, list(product(x, y)))) + x) & set(dic)
```

OUTPUT

```
{'computer', 'love', 'president'}
```

Comment: Yes, this one includes `house`. I don't know why people think it should not!

Comment: Your code won't work for Python 3+. They changed what map returns. For Python 3 you need to do:

    `set(list(map(''.join, list(product(x, y)))) + x + y) & set(dic)`


Otherwise really solid answer.

Comment: @ForFunAndProfit Thanks for pointing out. was waiting for OP to finalize the expected output though

Comment: The one issue I have with this sol'n is that it wouldn't capture 'president' if 'pre' and 'sident' list membership were reversed (i.e., it checks x + y but not y + x). OP isn't explicit about this, but my guess is that a complete solution should capture such cases. Otherwise, nice sol'n.

Comment: @Atlas order doesn't matter. What don't you go ahead and play with it

Comment: @mad_ Ex. of what I mean: `x=['casa','lo','sident','computer']` and `y=['music','sun','ve','pre','house']` which doesn't turn up 'president' with your code. Again, OP may or may not care about such cases--don't know enough about the context.

Comment: @Atlas I get it. You can add one more product `list(product(x,y))+list(product(y,x))` like this to solve that case. But it seems to be an overkill but definitely doable

Answer (score 0):

For a one liner use `filter` , `''.join` and add `['']` to the second list (so you don't have to do two `if`s):

```
list(filter(lambda i: i in dic, [''.join((s1, s2)) for s1 in x for s2 in (y + [''])]))
>>['love', 'president', 'computer']
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
x=['casa','lo','pre','computer']
y=['music','sun','ve','sident','house']
dic=['sunday','love','president','house','computer']

possibles = []
possibles += x
possibles += y # if you want the house...

hits = []
for a in x:
    for b in y:
        possibles.append(a+b)
for a in y:
    for b in x:
        possibles.append(a+b)

for p in possibles:
    if p in dic:
        hits.append(p)

print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straightforward version with nothing fancy. Others have suggested options that are likely more efficient; however, I think this solution captures your desired solution better than some (e.g., by checking all variations of concatenations).

You will want to use sets if you're doing a lot of lookups.

```
x = ['casa','lo','pre','computer']
y = ['music','sun','ve','sident','house']
dic = set(['sunday','love','president','house','computer'])
in_dic = set()
for str in y:
    if str in dic:
        in_dic.add(str)
for str1 in x:
    if str1 in dic:
        in_dic.add(str1)
    for str2 in y:
        str3 = str1 + str2
        str4 = str2 + str1
        if str3 in dic:
            in_dic.add(str3)
        if str4 in dic:
            in_dic.add(str4)

print(list(in_dic))
['president', 'love', 'computer', 'house']
```

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I need! Check all variables of concatenations

Comment: @NatáliaResende Thanks. Just made a small correction.