# concatenate pieces of a words separated in different lists

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

I have two lists of words/strings: x & y. The other part of some words in x are in y and I want to concatenate them.For example, I want to concatenate the word 'engage' from list x with its other part 'ments' from list y or 'operation' from list x with 'nelle' from list y. I also need to check in a dictionary if each word/token from list x exists in dic and the concatenated word exists in dic. If so, append them to another list (text). The code that I have been trying unsuccessfully is:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
x=['les', 'engage', 'président', 'de', 
'la', 'république', 'sont', 'aussi', 
'ceux', 'des', 'dirigeants', 'de', 'la', 
'société', 'ferroviaire', ',', 'a-t-il', 
'soutenu', 'de', 'élus', 'du', 'réunis', 
'à', '’', 'le', 'président', 'de', 'la', 
'république', ',', '(', 'à', 'droite', 
')', ',', 'aux', 'côtés', 'du', 'patron', 
'de', 'la', ',', 'guillaume', 'à', 'la', 
'gare', 'à', 'paris', ',', 'le', 
'juillet', 'der', '’', 'irrita', ',', 
'par', 'fois', ',', '’', 'usa', 'la', 
'face', 'aux', 'trains', 'supprimés', 
'aux', 'dessertes', 'abandonnées', 
'semble', 'avoir', 'aussi', 'saisi', 'le', 
'président', 'de', 'la', 'république', 
'.', 'devant', 'des', 'élus', 'du', ',', 
'réunis', 'mardi', 'février', 'à', '’', 
'le', 'cadre', 'du', 'grand', 'débat', 
',', 'a', 'eu', 'des', 'mots', 'très', 
'durs', 'contre', 'la', ',', 'qui', 'a', 
'fermé', 'la', 'ligne', '-', 'décembre', 
',', 'alors', 'que', 'le', 'chef', 'de', 
'’', '’', 'était', 'engagé', ',', 
'durant', 'un', 'déplacement', 'dans', 
'les', 'tué', 'en', 'avril', ',', 'à', 
'ce', '’', 'elle', 'reste', 'opération']


y=['ments', 'prési', 'républi', 'vant', 
'elysée', 'emmanuel', 'macron', 'cô', 
'pepy', 'montparnasse', 'geoffroy', 
'hasselt', '/', 'afp', 'tion', 'empare', 
'gers', 'més', 'elysée', 'emmanuel', 
'macron', 'epinal', 'etat', 'dépla', 
'cement', 'vosges', 'effec', 'nelle']

text=[ ]

with open ('Fr-dictionary.txt') as d:
dic = word_tokenize(d.read().lower())

for i in x:
  if i in dic:
    text.append(i)
  else:
    for j in y:
      concatenated = i + j
      if concatenated in dic:
        text.append(concatenated)

print(text)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: I found a similar question answered today and it's you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55163092/8472377

Comment: @Austin, yes, but the solution did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I manage to make your code working.

First I have to add `nltk.download('punkt')` just after `import nltk`

Then I commented my solution but feel free to ask if something is not clear:

```
cat_x_y = []
text = []

with open ('Fr-dictionary.txt') as d:
    dic = word_tokenize(d.read().lower())

#for each word in x check if they are in the dictonary 
for word in x:
    if word in dic:
        text.append(word)
#same for y
for word in y:
    if word in dic:
        text.append(word)

#for each word in x I want to add y and put it in cat_x_y
for i in range(len(x)):
    for word in y:
        cat_x_y.append(x[i]+word)

#for each word in y I want to add x and put it in cat_x_y
for j in range(len(y)):
    for word in x:
        cat_x_y.append(y[j]+word)

#remove duplicate in the cat_x_y:
cat_x_y = list(dict.fromkeys(cat_x_y))

#for each word in cat_x_y add the to text if they are in the dictionary
for word in cat_x_y:
    if word in dic:
        text.append(word)

#remove duplicate from text
text = list(dict.fromkeys(text))
print(text)
```

I assume that you want to check word from x and word from y.
But also try to add x+y and y+x

Here are the words I get when I execute the code:
[`'les', 'engage', 'président', 'de', 'la', 'république', 'sont', 'aussi', 'ceux', 'des', 'dirigeants', 'société', 'ferroviaire', 'a-t-il', 'soutenu', 'élus', 'du', 'réunis', 'à', 'le', 'droite', 'aux', 'côtés', 'patron', 'guillaume', 'gare', 'paris', 'juillet', 'der', 'irrita', 'par', 'fois', 'usa', 'face', 'trains', 'supprimés', 'dessertes', 'abandonnées', 'semble', 'avoir', 'saisi', 'devant', 'mardi', 'février', 'cadre', 'grand', 'débat', 'a', 'eu', 'mots', 'très', 'durs', 'contre', 'qui', 'fermé', 'ligne', 'décembre', 'alors', 'que', 'chef', 'était', 'engagé', 'durant', 'un', 'déplacement', 'dans', 'tué', 'en', 'avril', 'ce', 'elle', 'reste', 'opération', 'engagements', 'lavant', 'lamés', 'lacement', 'levant', 'irritation', 'usagers', 'avant', 'quenelle', 'cenelle', 'opérationnelle', 'préside', 'présides', 'présider', 'vantaux', 'vanta', 'mésusa', 'déplace', 'effectué']`

Comment: Thank you very much, but I cannot have the 'engage' and 'engagement' and 'déplace' and 'déplacement' in the same list. The purpose of this program is to join the parts of one word that were separated by the line breaks. The output has have the same words and same word order of the original text.

Comment: Can you provide a short dummy exemple with x, y and the final text to be sure we are looking for the same process?
Thanks!